# Magento 2.3.2: Database prefix error running setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2.3.2, setup-upgrade

I tried to install MailChimp extension through Composer, but when running setup:upgrade I received a database error. Assuming that the problem was in the extension, I restored the backup I made just before installing the extension. Out of curiosity I run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" again and received the same database error!
The error I get is:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mg2_mg_catalogrule_product_price_replica' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE mg2_mg_catalogrule_product_price_replica

The prefix of my database is 'mg2_' and somewhere something assumes the table name starts with 'mg_' and then glues even my prefix in front of it.

I didn't have this problem after the last extension I installed. How can I find out what and where a wrong table name is assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento dev docs for [Installing and upgrading the database schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/) shows the code and functions called on `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

However the mailchimp code doesn't seem to reference this, it would have been in  [mailchimp/mc-magento2/Setup/InstallSchema.php](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/blob/develop-2.3/Setup/InstallSchema.php) .

`catalogrule_product_price_replica` is a table associated with indexing, it might be that the crons are still running indexing or indexing.  Please be sure you are in [maintenance mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html) `php bin/magento maintenance:enable` before `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.  Also please ensure indexing is up to date and running correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I was abroad for a week.... I've found out the problem is not in MailChimp indeed but in the fact I cloned the website a while ago using Installatron. It renamed all my database tables with a different prefix (from "mg_" to "mg2_" and apparently somehow it gets confused. 
I will check indexing and if something in the database scheme is changed with double prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but it took more work than expected. A while ago I cloned the website using Installatron and apparently it created also a clone of all database tables. Where the original tables had prefix "mg_" the cloned tables got the prefix "mg2_". However, cloning only copied tables, nothing more. Hence to solve the problem I had to:

- Create all triggers for tables with prefix mg2_
- Rename all constraints with prefix mg_ to prefix mg2_
- In table "sales_sequence_meta" change all records referring to tables with prefix mg_ to prefix mg2_
- Remove all old tables with prefix mg_

And now it all works again.
Since I was set on the right track by the comment that the original error message referred to a table related to the indexer I will accept that answer as the solution.